# Can't seem to edit questions but can edit answers

Tags: support, google-chrome

I'm looking for guidance on how to diagnose a problem with editing questions.

The symptoms are that when I click edit the tags list is not matched to the tag database and the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button is greyed out and cannot be clicked.

[image: picture of the faulty interface]

This occurs across the Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow platforms. However, if I open an "Incognito" window and make an anonymous edit, it works.:

I can also edit from another machine on a different network as myself.

I have rebooted the machine and updated the browser but the symptoms remain.

I'm using Chrome <sub>Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)</sub> On Windows 7.

What could cause this, as it has only just started today, after some internet service interruptions followed by a system update!

---

Update:

I get errors shown in the Developer Console:

```
how-to-work-with-doj…oveable-events:1886 GET https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200 (OK)
stub.en.js?v=3e2db6f04a22:1 GET https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/tageditornew.en.js?v=8a1817fbdfcc net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200
stub.en.js?v=3e2db6f04a22:1 GET https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/begin-edit-event.en.js?v=3238dd301e69 net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200
```

​

Comment: If you open a developer console, any errors?

Comment: @rene: Yes, added to Q

Comment: That error seems to indicate that your content is not gzipped while it does expect it is: https://superuser.com/a/291707/172195 could it be that your cache somehow got corrupted and it now serves stale data? Did you try a clear data: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050? You only need to get rid of images and files of the last 24 hours I guess.

Comment: @rene: yes. That did  the trick. Thank you....